# Maximum string size for Sonos custom service strings and translations file (strings.xml)?

Tags: sonos

I'm setting up a custom service using the Sonos API. Apart from "ServicePromo" is there a maximum size or length for the strings defined in strings.xml? For example, could I make this string ridiculously long?

```
<string stringId="SAVE_TRACK">Some really ... really long string.</string>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, the string length on error messages is 125 characters.   (http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/460)

The short description has a limit of 160 characters.

The other fields, while technically not having a hard limit, there is a practical limit on what will be able to display.